# How do I freeze the cell value from a formula once past a certain date?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of cells (Sheet1!E3:E55) that use a formula to pull a calculated completion percentage from a specific cell on a different sheet (Sheet2!C7).

I would like the calculated value for a cell in that range (i.e. Sheet1!E3) to turn static/lock the cell value at that time, at a date specified in another cell on that sheet (i.e. Sheet1!A4).

I know this requires VBA, but I am a noob with this and haven't been able to find anything via google. Thank you!!!

I've tried various formulas but found through my google searching that this is only achievable with a macro. I tried recording my own macro to copy and then paste the value of the cell, but that would only work for that one cell, not the range. Unfortunately I don't know enough about VBA to edit the code to get what I'm after.

Comment: Instead of locking the cell with VBA (which is also fine, if that's what you want), you can prefix your formula with a check of the date, e.g. `=IF(thisdate>Sheet1!$A$4,<the rest of your formula>...`. See [here](https://www.exceldemy.com/how-to-lock-and-unlock-cells-in-excel-using-vba/) on how to lock the cells with VBA.

Comment: Thanks Peter, but I'm looking to prevent the target cell value from updating when the reference cell recalculates. I essentially want a snapshot of that cell value at each date in my "date" column.

Here is what I currently have in cell GraphData!E3 (which I want to stop updating at the date in A4):
=Summary!$C$7

Cell C7 contains:
=Summary!AVERAGE(C8:C57)

Say GraphDataA4 has a date of 1/08/2024, and cell GraphDataA5 has a date of 1/15/2024. I'd like for GraphDataE3 to "freeze" the calculated value based on the date in A4 - then have E4 "freeze" the value based on A5.... etc.

Comment: Without seeing exactly how your data is arranged on both sheets, it's impossible to understand how the formulas are working to produce data based on a date. You can add some sample data to your post above. However, I would probably add some "helper" rows or columns to your data where each column is based on a different date. Then you can easily pull in your average by date on the other sheet.

Answer (score -1):

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Right Click On "Sheet1" Tab and
    ' Select "View Code" and paste the following code
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    Dim FreezVal As Long, LastRow As Long, x As Long
    Dim FreezOnDate As Date, rowItemDate As Date
    Dim ws As Workbook
    
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook
    Set sh1 = ws.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh2 = ws.Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    FreezOnDate = CDate(sh2.Range("E7").Value)  'refer to Sheet2!E7 value
    LastRow = sh1.Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row   'find last row of data in Sheet1
    
      For x = 3 To LastRow   ''In Sheet1 loop till last row and compare value in cell E7 in Sheet2
      
        rowItemDate = CDate(sh1.Range("A" & x).Value)
        FreezVal = sh1.Range("E" & x).Value
        
        sh1.Range("D" & x).Value = "=" & sh1.Range("c" & x).Address & "/" & sh1.Range("B" & x).Address
          
          If rowItemDate = FreezOnDate Then
          
            sh1.Range("D" & x).Value = Range("D" & x).Value
            sh1.Range("A" & x, "D" & x).Font.Color = vbBlue ''freezed row highlighted
          
          Else
          
           sh1.Range("A" & x, "D" & x).Font.Color = vbBlack
           
          End If
        
      Next x
    End Sub
```